# if statement syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, grep

```
if [ (`grep -R -l "${images}" *` | wc -l) == 1 ]
```

This is not working. If I do this at the command line then it will give me a number.

```
grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l
```

I want to see if that number is a 1. If it is do something. If not do something else. Why is the first code chunk giving me a sytax error?

I have updated my code. image_count is correct with the number but for some reason it is always doing the else even if $image_count is really 1. So my if statement isn't right. Anyone know why?

```
image_count=`grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l`
echo $image_count
if [ $image_count == 1 ]; then
new_name=`grep -R -l "slide[0-9]"`
echo new_name
else
echo "non 1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

> So my if statement isn't right. Anyone
>   know why?

Well it's the *test statement* (within `[ ]`) that seems wrong.
It's kind of mixing up two languages: bash's command language (which are commands,executables  piped together +  control flow syntax).

OTOH, within the `[]` above, it's an expression language of the `test` program, see the manpage: [$ man test](http://www.mediacollege.com/cgi-bin/man/page.cgi?topic=test) : "( EXPRESSION )" .

Expression there is *not* an arbitrary shell command, but something built up from primitives (strings, numbers,etc) and operators (-eq, -oe).

One bridge between these two languages is of course the backtick- which runs the bash command therein and substitutes the output *as a string*, which `test` then can work with.

So, as others replied briefly, just move out the backticks to the boundary of the left side, ie from:

```
if [ (`grep -R -l "${images}" *` | wc -l) == 1 ]
```

to

```
if [ `grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l` = 1 ]
```

UPDATE: looking at your second version, the other problem is `==` is not a valid operator in `test` (again, see manpage). Use plain `=` instead.

On the other hand, `==` is supported by a bash itself (in recent enough versions) - a bit confusing..

Comment: Just a suggestion: you may wish to use $() instead of `` for capturing the output of commands.  $() nests and `` tends to lead to character escaping issues.  Eg: $(grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l) is equivalent to the backtick'd form.

Comment: sure, I actually agree - just too used to `s.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if [ `grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l` == 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo=`grep -R -l "${images"} * | wc -l`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    if [ $foo == 1 ]; then
        echo "1 file found";
    else
        echo "$foo files found";
    fi
else 
    echo "no files found";
fi
```

Comment: I have updated my original code. My if statement isn't working right now. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `grep -R -l "${images}" * | wc -l` == "1" ]; then
  echo "hazzar!"
fi
```

Comment: need a space after the opening `[`

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the complicated pipe usage and use the '-c' option of grep to output the count of matching lines.

```
if [ $( grep -rlc "${images}" * ) -eq 1 ]; then
```

Multiple things here, using '-c' and comparing to a number 1, vs a string 1.
(-R and -r are equivalent per the grep manual)